# Pair To Mac In Visual Studio 2022 Over Internet Won't Connect

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to set up a mac mini in a remote location so that I can pair to mac in Visual Studio 2022. Everything works fine when I'm in that location and on the local network, but when I leave and try to connect via an ip address, I get a "Couldn't resolve Mac "xxx"" error. I have forwarded ports 5900 for VNC, 22 for SSH, and 5000 and 50530 for Xamarin messaging. I can ssh and vnc into the machine from outside the local network just fine. When I connect to pair with mac, I put in the subdomain pointing to the public ip address as "xxx.xxx.com" and get the error. If I put in the ip address it also just fails "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". Both machines are up to date with latest versions of Visual Studio (for windows and mac) and Xamarin. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DevenCC it seems like you linked to a private azure devops instance that I can't log into, but to answer your question yes. When connecting outside of the local network you have to pair it manually. It's not recognizing it though even though I believe I have the necessary ports forwarded properly.

Comment: Sorry about that, indeed seems my clipboard didn't copy the page link 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-7.0#manually-add-a-mac

Comment: The only other noteworthy aspect to this might be the different mac "sharing settings" for prompted connection inside vs outside the network. It might allow connections from inside the network, but not outside.

Comment: in VS when you are inside the same network, all you'd need to do is add the machine as XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX ; outside however, you might have to add as "ssh username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" 

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp1066/mac

Comment: @DevenCC thank you for the helpful comments. Your new link works. Yes I'm using that manual connection. Your second comment about the mac sharing settings limiting connections from outside the local network is a good point and what I'm looking into now. The machine does not have a firewall specified, but it could still potentially be the issue. The last comment about using a different connection syntax did not solve the issue.

Comment: That's a shame that nothing seems to work. I can't seem to find any documentation supporting that pairing to a mac outside the local network is not supported. That being said, I've never heard of someone having that type of setup. I am afraid I am at a lost for more insight, but please update if you have any new development.